# Retrieving Ref Cursor using Classic ASP

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, cursor, oracle8

Looking for help on Classic ASP. I have a Oracle 8 Stored Procedure which returns Cursor output. I would like to call SP on in ASP page and display the data in a table format by looping all result set rows.

Here is the code which i tried:

```
Dim conn, cmd, rs 

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("adodb.connection") 

With conn
    .ConnectionString=strConnect
    .Open
End With

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command") 
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
cmd.CommandText = "Ref_Cursor_Output_Procedure" 
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc 

Dim param1 
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter ("pid", adInteger, adParamInput) 
cmd.Parameters.Append param1 
param1.Value = 30 

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.BOF Or rs.EOF 
 -- Do something 
 rs.MoveNext 
Loop 

rs.Close
```

Please have a look and let me know if anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```vbs
Dim cn, rs, cmd, param  
set cn = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
cn.Open Cstr(strConnect)   '"Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=xxxx;User ID=xx;Password=xx"    
set cmd = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    set .ActiveConnection   = cn
    .CommandText    =  "{call ref_cursor_procedure({resultset 0, t_cursor})}"
    .CommandType    = 1
end with

set rs = server.CreateObject ( "ADODB.Recordset" ) 
set rs = cmd.execute

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.BOF Or rs.EOF 
 -- Do something 
 rs.MoveNext 
Loop 

rs.Close
```

It worked well.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error, or just no result?

If no result, try changing

```
Do Until rs.BOF Or rs.EOF
```

to

```
Do Until rs.EOF
```